# Python - Send message to user whilst in input prompt

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, events, prompt

I have the following python program (obviously actual program is much more complicated)

```
def commandAssignment(username):
    cmd = input("{0}>".format(username))
    if cmd.lower().split(" ")[0] == "print":
        for i in cmd.lower().split(" "):
            if i == "print":
                pass
            else:
                print(i, end=" ")
        print()
    else:
        print("Invalid.")

# Some authentication stuff checks password and sets username and machinename variables
while True:
    commandAssignment(username + "@" + machinename)
```

The user sees the following:

```
jay@dev2> print Hello World
Hello World
jay@dev2> hduilgwebflfg
Invalid.
jay@dev2>
```

I would like to completely rework code so that user can be sent messages while on the prompt, for example to say a job they started has finished.

I have looked into this and have figured this will probably have to be event driven. For example, I have a seperate script that calls my http api every 10 seconds. When it detects a change, it sends a message to the main script telling it to print the message. Only problem is, I have no idea how to do this, and would appreciate any pointers / code that could give me a nudge in the right direction.

EDIT: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am using python3 :-)

Comment: You will need threading.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could do that?